# python all possible products between columns

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have a numpy matrix X and I would like to add to this matrix as new variables all the possible products between 2 columns.

```
So if X=(x1,x2,x3) I want X=(x1,x2,x3,x1x2,x2x3,x1x3)
```

Is there an elegant way to do that?
I think a combination of numpy and itertools should work

EDIT:
Very good answers but are they considering that X is a matrix? So x1,x1,.. x3 can eventually be arrays?

EDIT:
A Real example

```
a=array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Answer (score 3):

[Itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) should be the answer here.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
p = (x * y for x, y in itertools.combinations(a, 2))
print list(itertools.chain(a, p))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6] # 1, 2, 3, 2 x 1, 3 x 1, 3 x 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I think Samy's solution is pretty good. If you *need* to use numpy, you could transform it a little like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from numpy import prod

x = [1, 2, 3]
print x + map(prod, combinations(x, 2))
```

Gives the same output as Samy's solution:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your arrays are small, then [Samy's pure-Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22042088/68063) using [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) should be fine:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def all_products1(a):
    p = (x * y for x, y in combinations(a, 2))
    return list(chain(a, p))
```

But if your arrays are large, then you'll get a substantial speedup by fully vectorizing the computation, using [`numpy.triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html), like this:

```
import numpy as np

def all_products2(a):
    x, y = np.triu_indices(len(a), 1)
    return np.r_[a, a[x] * a[y]]
```

Let's compare these:

```
>>> data = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (10000,))
>>> timeit(lambda:all_products1(data), number=1)
53.745754408999346
>>> timeit(lambda:all_products2(data), number=1)
12.26144006299728
```

The solution using `numpy.triu_indices` also works for multi-dimensional data:

```
>>> np.random.uniform(0, 100, (3,2))
array([[ 63.75071196,  15.19461254],
       [ 94.33972762,  50.76916376],
       [ 88.24056878,  90.36136808]])
>>> all_products2(_)
array([[   63.75071196,    15.19461254],
       [   94.33972762,    50.76916376],
       [   88.24056878,    90.36136808],
       [ 6014.22480172,   771.41777239],
       [ 5625.39908354,  1373.00597677],
       [ 8324.59122432,  4587.57109368]])
```

If you want to operate on columns rather than rows, use:

```
def all_products3(a):
    x, y = np.triu_indices(a.shape[1], 1)
    return np.c_[a, a[:,x] * a[:,y]]
```

For example:

```
>>> np.random.uniform(0, 100, (2,3))
array([[ 33.0062385 ,  28.17575024,  20.42504351],
       [ 40.84235995,  61.12417428,  58.74835028]])
>>> all_products3(_)
array([[   33.0062385 ,    28.17575024,    20.42504351,   929.97553238,
          674.15385734,   575.4909246 ],
       [   40.84235995,    61.12417428,    58.74835028,  2496.45552756,
         2399.42126888,  3590.94440122]])
```

Comment: I have  a big array so your solutions would be good.  the problem is that you are adding lines. I would like to add columns.